# vb.net excel merging cells confusion

Tags: vb.net, excel, merge, office-interop

Hey all I am trying to wrap my head around how to go about merging 2 cells together though it seems easy, I can't seem to get a grasp of how its calling the cells, rows, columns, etc from my code below:

```
Dim mergeCell As Excel.Range = xlsSheet.Range("B" & i & ":B" & i)
mergeCell.Range(mergeCell.Cells(0, 0), mergeCell.Cells(1, 1)).Merge()
```

**'i'** above would be **4** in this case below. My original sheet looks like this:

[image]

Where I want to **merge A4/A5 with B4/5**. Likewise, I will need to be also able to **merge A8 with B8**, etc etc.

However, when I run that code it merges A6/A7 with B6/B7:

[image]

When I use this code **before** the merge:

```
mergeCell.Select()
```

It seems to outline the **.1** cell:

[image]

Can someone make since of the **mergeCell.Cells(0, 0), mergeCell.Cells(1, 1)** code?

Comment: Why don't you use a formula and use concatenate function?

Comment: Mind showing an example of that, @Zaggler?

Comment: Give me a few minutes please, I will get you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I **finally** figured it out:

```
xlsSheet.Range("A" & i & ":B" & (i + 1)).MergeCells = True
```

But I would like to see the example from you, @Zaggler.

Answer (score 0):

why not to use the `.Merge()` method:

```
  Dim rng As Excel.Range = Nothing
            rng = xlsSheet.Range(xlsSheet.Cells(1, i), xlsSheet.Cells(2, i+1))
            rng.Merge()
```

you did it almost right in the original question, you just need to change:

```
mergeCell.Range(mergeCell.Cells(0, 0), mergeCell.Cells(1, 1))
```

to

```
mergeCell.Range(xlsSheet.Cells(0, 0), xlsSheet.Cells(1, 1))
```